# When I use DataSnapshot with if else then it shows null value instead of original value, why?

Tags: firebase, android-studio, kotlin

When I use the `Update_User_Information()` after `else if` then `dataSnapshot.value.toString()` shows null value and because of that `Update_User_Information()` gets executed.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseAuth.uid!!).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.value.toString().contains(signup_username)) {
            progressDialog.dismiss()
            binding.signupUsername.error = "This username is already registered"
            return
        }
        else if (dataSnapshot.value.toString().contains(signup_phone)) {
            progressDialog.dismiss()
            binding.signupUsername.error = "This Phone Number is already registered"
            return
        }
        Toast.makeText(this@Signup, dataSnapshot.value.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() // shows null
        Update_User_Information()
    }
    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(this@Signup, "There is a problem in database. Please report this issue to support.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
})
```

but if I use same code with a litte change then it works but it also executes the

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseAuth.uid!!).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.value.toString().contains(signup_username)) {
            progressDialog.dismiss()
            binding.signupUsername.error = "This username is already registered"
        }
        else if (dataSnapshot.value.toString().contains(signup_phone)) {
            progressDialog.dismiss()
            binding.signupUsername.error = "This username is already registered"
        }

    }

    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(this@Signup, "There is a problem in database. Please report this issue to support.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
})
Update_User_Information()
```

What I am trying to do is, checking the username and phone number if it's registered in my database or not, if it's found in my database then I don't want to execute `Update_User_Information()`. Any solution ?

[Here is the image of my databse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHpHn.png)

Comment: Please don't post duplicate [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69419462/datasnapshot-value-is-null-when-used-with-else-or-bellow-else-if?noredirect=1#comment122738386_69419462).

Comment: I didn't found any solution :(, Can you help me pls ? @AlexMamo